# What should I do to avoid wetting my pants while peeing?

Tags: home, personal-care

The last few drops after peeing remain on my penis which wets my underwear or my pant if there is no underwear(which makes situation even worse).Also I would be happy if someone tells me how to pee in urinal properly to avoid any nasty affair.

Comment: Hi gateprep, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE.

Comment: The "how to pee in urinal properly" should be asked as a separate question, if you're still interested to get answer to it. (and remove that part from here. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underwear is one way to isolate your expensive outerwear from your body's various daily glandular functions and their waste such as skin cells, hair, sweat, oils, etc. Urine is just one of them that you've recently noticed.

Some males wipe or "blot" (soak-up) the moisture with a small piece of toilet tissue that they discard when they flush or put into waste before washing their hands. Some hold the base of their penis and quickly "flick" the remaining droplet(s) from it into the urinal. Some squeeze the excess by working from the base of their penis to the end forcing the remaining moisture from it. Some press the base of their penis behind the testicles to accomplish the same thing.

Try different things and go with what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

While [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/18626/1399) is correct and pretty much what I always do, I did notice something over the years so want to give my two cents.

When I'm urinating with the jeans still all the way up, meaning through the zipper, there is much more "leftover" urine when I'm done. Even after wiping with paper, squeezing, etc... there is still urine left which sometimes reach the underwear. Interesting enough, when urinating with the jeans/pants down, i.e. with penis exposed, there is much less leftover urine when I'm done, and it's easily cleaned in the methods described on the other answer.

Bottom line: pee with the pants down, and it should be easier to avoid getting the leftover pee from reaching your pants. Pants don't have to be all the way down of course, knee level is just enough, so it can also be used in urinals.