# How to clean my private part after peeing as a man in a public restroom without drawing unnecessary attention?

Tags: personal-care

I learned from [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/18626/5152) that there are many methods to clean the end of the penis after urinating, but normally it's unnecessary. However, it's very necessary for me because having my briefs get wet this way makes me feel quite unclean.

When there is no one around me, I usually dab the tip using a small piece of toilet tissue or use my right hand to wipe the moisture off; but when I am surrounded by someone, or I thought someone over there can notice what I will do, I would just shake off and/or squeeze out the last drops.

How can I overcome my concerns and conveniently clean my dick after peeing? I don't want to pee like girls because sometimes it's very hard to find a toilet seat in a public restroom.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are concerned that someone will see you use tissue or toilet paper to clean the last drops? I don't think it can be seen as something inappropriate or that one should be ashamed to do.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Usually I see no one does that. I think it's kind of a social pressure or crowd mentality. Doing that seems to be a little bit effeminate.

Comment: I think that most people just don't care that much to have the leftovers in the underwear, so they don't spend time cleaning afterwards. I tried to think of ways to answer your question here, so far didn't find anything but if something will pop to my mind I'll gladly share it.

Comment: this whole "cleaning yourself is girly" thing is causing so much misery. Clean yourself, start a trend, be manly and brave instead of timidly putting up with dampness.

Comment: @Kate I think the issue here isn't being "girly" in front of others, but rather the case of "feeling clean" which I can understand, even if personally I don't care that much for those few drops.

Comment: From Kate... in some locations an attendant will hand you a piece of tissue for that purpose. And re "I would just shake off and/or squeeze out the last drops" isn't that what people do *before* dabbing with tissue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaking it like a polaroid picture might work at home, but in public restrooms, that strategy can backfire.

The easiest solution is a quick dab with some toilet paper. Most guys do it, and nobody bats an eye.  Think of it as a silent handshake among men – a universal sign of "been there, done that." I don't think you should be concerned about this.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel uncomfortable about using paper in the open area of the restroom make use of the cubicles which are usually also available.
You do not have to sit down when you are in one.

Comment: Well in rush hours, it's hard to find available cubicle, think that's what OP meant in the last sentence (*sometimes it's very hard to find a toilet seat in a public restroom*), but anyway I agree that's pretty much the ideal way.

Comment: Try being a woman, we always have to queue.

Comment: I know, had my share of waiting for gf/wife while she's in the toilets... anyway something off topic - your website isn't working ([the link in your profile](http://knopen.ismijnhobby.nl.bales.id.au/)) - just FYA. :)